# Reading CSV file with Streamreader getting (index of ouf range exception) on empty or wrong formated rules how to avoid

Tags: vb.net, csv, streamreader

Oke so i read an CSV file with streamreader and get the exception index out of range when it reads an empty line or when the line is not in the correct format.

is there an solution that when you get this error you go to the next line of the csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to avoid parsing CSV manually at all and use one of the available CSV-readers instead. For example [this fast CSV-reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader).

---

Instead of reacting on exceptions i would skip empty lines in the first place.

Instead of a `StreamReader` you could also use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) with Linq:

```
Dim lines = From line In File.ReadLines(path)
            Where line.Length <> 0
' now you can enumerate all not-empty lines '
For Each line In lines
    ' ... '
Next
```

If you insist on a `Streamreader`:

```
Using sr = New StreamReader(path)
    While Not sr.EndOfStream
        Dim line = sr.ReadLine()
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then
            ' ... '
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

Comment: Tanx for the fast reaction and the code but this code only works when the line you read in is completely empty but i have a line in it whit a value like this (.85,14) where all the other values are missing and the error also occurs do you also have a solution for this.

Comment: Tanx for reaction il take a look at your link